# Excel VBA Inventory sorting

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make the inventory scan process a bit simple. 
We scan the incoming shipment. The scanner sends a string to Excel something like `'XYZ123'`.
What I'm trying to do is, instead of the user selecting the column manually, I'd like excel to send the scanned string to the respective column. 
For example, let us say there are 3 possible columns `'PO'`, `'Item'`, `'SN'`

- `PO` will start with `'XYZ'`
- `Item` will start with `'ABC'`
- `SN` with start with `'LMN'`

If the scanned value starts with `'ABC'`, it has to be sent to the `'Item'` column.

Is this possible? I tried playing with the Search, Exact and few other formulas, nothing worked so far.

Thank you,

Comment: You cant do this with formulas - you'll need to use VBA. you can use the `Worksheet_Change` event handler to check what value has been scanned in and copy it to the required position.

Comment: I couldn't see Excel being used as a live-update type system, if that is what you intended. I've made Worksheet_Change solutions in the past and they can cause upkeep problems over time with new users or macros not being enabled, etc. Maybe you could scan them all to one column and separate them at the end of the job? You could create a bucket formula which is a concatenation of `IF(LEFT(A1,3)="XYZ","PO","")&IF(LEFT(A1,3)="ABC","SN","")` to group by.

Comment: How is the scanner sending a string to Excel? You might need to analyze the string in that step and then send it to the appropriate column from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test_inventory_sorting()
  Dim v_arr(1 To 3) As String, v As Variant
  v_arr(1) = "XYZ1234"
  v_arr(2) = "LMN73456"
  v_arr(3) = "ABCzxcv"

  For Each v In v_arr
    Debug.Print v; " goes to "; get_col(CStr(v))
  Next v
End Sub
Function get_col(ByVal p_val As String) As String
  If p_val Like "ABC*" Then
    get_col = "SN"
  ElseIf p_val Like "LMN*" Then
    get_col = "Item"
  ElseIf p_val Like "XYZ*" Then
    get_col = "PO"
  Else
    get_col = "Invalid"
  End If
End Function
```